# Как настроить AVD на максимальную производительность?

Tags: avd, эмулятор, android, отладка

Пытаясь запустить *`Hello World`* приложение на [**`AVD`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) из [**Android SDK**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html) столкнулся с проблемой: *эмулятор сильно глючит и даже меню открывает на протяжении нескольких секунд.*

---

Посоветуйте, как заставить его работать нормально. [Использовать физический девайс](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) - не вариант, так как *сдох* **`MiniUSB-разъем`**.

Comment: Может у тебя диск С заполнен?

Comment: Нет, *играю в GTA IV со свёрнутым MS Flight Simulator* XD, и на диске **`C:`** места `20Гб` из `100` свободно...

Comment: А какой девайс? Там вроде с 2.3.x как то лучше стало 

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

посмотри тут (на 4.0.3 все старое должно пойти), как ни странно работать должен побыстрее

Comment: А вообще советую все-таки продумать тестирование на реальном устройстве (поставь тот же дропбокс и просто кидай новую версию программы, устанавливай тестируй, правда логи не посмотреть, но хоть увидишь слабые места и повторишь в эмуляторе, там уже и логи посмотришь)

Comment: Я понял, что виртуальный какой именно 2.1, 2.2 ? И вот по моей ссылке попробуй поставить GPU emulation. Вроде помогает (у меня терпимо работает эмулятор, но все равно стараюсь на реальном проверять)

Comment: 1. Поставить галочку Use Snapshot (не помню точное название)  
2. Запускать AVD на Linux. Я на одной и той же машине ощутимо чувствую разницу в скорости АВД в пользу Linuxa.  
3. Если программа пишется с совместимостью андроид 2.х, то и АВД использовать этой версии (4.х тормозит ужасно). То есть 4.х использовать для проверки совместимости, а основную отладку производить в 2.х

Comment: @rasmisha, 2.3.3, **`GPU emulation`** помог, но всё равно заметно тормозит, *на физический кидать выйдет дольше: пока карту памяти вытащу, пока к компу подключу её...*

Comment: @ReinRaus как раз-таки use snapshot убирается и GPU emulation true и лично у меня 4.0.3 шустрее работает нежели 2.x

Comment: Ники, при чем здесь флэшка? Ставите дропбокс на компьютер и телефон, с компа бросаете новый установщик на ДБ. Пока Вы возьмете телефон в руки уже все синхронизируется, если скорость интернета нормальная.

Comment: @ReinRaus, на счёт **`Linux`** - проблематично *- придётся хакинтош удалять XD*, **`UseSnapshot`** поставлю, но он конфликтует с **`GPUemulation`**.

**`Wi-Fi`** дома нету, а через **`BT`** - руки не доходят на девайс поставить приложение, которое позволяет **`apk`** принимать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неплохой вариант - использовать Android x86 в связке с Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager . Работает намного быстрее чем стандартный. Правда я столкнулся с проблемой: среда Idea показывает эмулятор connected но offline. Может в эклипсе всё нормуль. 
Инструкция: [Intel® Atom™ x86 Image for Android* Ice Cream Sandwich Installation Instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-ice-cream-sandwich-installation-instructions-recommended/)

Comment: @alvin, я о нём тоже думал, всё-таки **`x86`** а значит процессор не *`эмулирует`*, так что **работать быстрее должен**,* но есть такая проблема, что у меня он ошибку выкидывает и не хочет **`AVD`** добавлять...*